# Xcode 8.3 Debug Issues Sometime

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I am facing issues while debugging which was not there in the previous version of Xcode. While I am running the app in the simulator I am not able to debug also breakpoints don't work. This is some random issues and doesn't happen every time. I have checked with two different systems and I find same in both. Also, I checked when the debug is not working in debug navigator there is no debug session but app is actually running in debug mode.

Did anyone face this issues and any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue couple of times. Force quitting xcode worked for me.